# Browser fixed height with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I have my window/ browser actual height? for example `alert($(window).height());` it gives me 639 at full screen but when I reduce the browser height it gives less height. I need always 639 though I reduce the browser height. Is it possible with any jQuery or Javascript method?
NB.`alert(window.screen.availHeight);` gives the height with toolbar which is bigger than 639(my window height) which I don't want actually.

Thanks.

Comment: where do you call `alert($(window).height());`?

Comment: Are you saying that you always want the browser window to be 639px in height, or that you want to store the 639px value for use later when the window has changed size?

Comment: You can use the [resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) function

Comment: I want always it should give me 639. - Rory McCrossan

Comment: `alert($(window).height()); ` value gets change with resize which is not desired in my case.